# How to return the second value in a "nested subscribe" pattern?

Tags: angular, subscribe

In an Angular 7 app, I've got a method part of a service, which has to return an `Observable` to be in turn subscribed by some client code.

This method is built on a "nested subscribes" pattern, about what I read BTW that it's kind of an anti-pattern. But to be honest, I'm not skilled enough in Angular to replace it.

The code looks pretty much as follows:

```
public signIn(customer): Observable<Customer> {
        return this.apiProvider.getCustomerTokens(customer)
            .pipe(map(token => {
                return this.apiProvider.getCustomer(token)
                    .subscribe(customerData => {
                        // some code here...
                    });
            }));
    }
```

It causes a synchronous issue, probably due to the fact that the first `return` is interpreted before the second, despite the client code actually, need to subscribe to the *second* return value.

Any ideas on how to make it work properly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use switchMap.

```
public signIn(customer): Observable<Customer> {
        return this.apiProvider.getCustomerTokens(customer)
            .pipe(switchMap(token => this.apiProvider.getCustomer(token))
    }
```

Then, subscribe to the returned observable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using [switchmap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) to wait for the first response and then do another

```
public signIn(customer): Observable<Customer> {
        return this.apiProvider.getCustomerTokens(customer)
            .switchMap(token => {
                return this.apiProvider.getCustomer(token); 
            }).subscribe(customerData => {
                        // some code here...
                    });
    }
```